# Copying a range of numbers from regedit to multiple worksheets depending on tabstrip index?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, userform, vba

I am attempting to create a userform in EXCEL/VBA that will allow you to select a range of data and copy the data range to a particular worksheet depending on the tabstrip index, once the commandbutton "forecast" is selected.

This is what i have so far for the tabstrip change:

```
Private Sub tbsMethod_Change()
Dim tabIndex As Integer
tabIndex = tbsMethod.SelectedItem.Index
Select Case tabIndex
Case 0
Label2.Visible = True
RefEdit1.Visible = True
Label_a.Visible = False
Label_b.Visible = False
Label_g.Visible = False
TextBox_a.Visible = False
TextBox_b.Visible = False
TextBox_g.Visible = False
Case 1
Label2.Visible = True
....
```

This is where I believe the problem is (commandbutton_click):

```
Sub ForecastButton_Click()
Dim tabIndex As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
tabIndex = tbsMethod.SelectedItem.Index
With ThisWorkbook
Select Case tabIndex
'copies to worksheet or "module"
Case 0
Application.GoTo ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7")
Range(RefEdit1.Value).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B7:B26")
Case 1
Range(RefEdit1.Value).Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Range("B7:B26")
Application.GoTo ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B7")
Case 2
Application.GoTo ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B7")
.Cells(29, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_a.Value
Range(RefEdit1.Value).Copy Destination:=Sheet4.Range("B7:B26")
Case 3
Application.GoTo ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B7")
.Cells(29, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_a.Value
.Cells(30, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_b.Value
Range(RefEdit1.Value).Copy Destination:=Sheet5.Range("B7:B26")

Case 4
Application.GoTo ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("B7")
.Cells(29, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_a.Value
.Cells(30, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_b.Value
.Cells(31, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_g.Value
Range(RefEdit1.Value).Copy Destination:=Sheet6.Range("B7:B26")

End Select
Unload dfMod
End With

Me.R.Value = ""
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload dfMod
End Sub
```

I was getting the error message "Error 9 Subscript out of range".
Now it is saying "Method or Data member not found."
Fairly new to VBA/EXCEL so any help would be much appreciated

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Is there any line within your code where error stop the procedure? I've never could rely on `RefEdit` format. Please consider using `Application.InputBox(,Type:=8)`

Comment: when the error is being thrown you should see the lines containing errors highlighted in yellow. please post them here

Comment: The error states: "Compile error : method or data member not found"

Comment: The following line is highlighted in yellow "Sub ForecastButton_Click()"

Answer (score 1):

You have in your code

```
With thisworkbook
    ...
    .cells(...
```

`cells` is not a property or method of the `workbook` object and will return an error